# R: error with autofitVariogram (automap package)

Tags: r, runtime-error, automap

Using autofitVariogram() function from automap package I have generate following error:

> Error in vgm_list[[which.min(SSerr_list)]] :  attempt to select less
>   than one element in get1index

Example code:

```
model <- as.formula(Value ~ Elevation)
data <- matrix(c(11.07,42.75,5,62.5,
                 8.73,45.62,234,75,
                 12.62,44.03,12,75,
                 10.87,45.38,67,75,
                 8.79,42.53,64,75),
               nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
names(data) <- c('Lon', 'Lat', 'Elevation', 'Value')
library('sp')
coordinates(data) = ~Lon+Lat
library('automap')
autofitVariogram(model, data)
```

What causes this error? Do interpolated values cause some kind of 'singularity'?

Thx!

Comment: Developer of automap here. I think this is more related to a quirk in automap, not to some more general statical problem. I'll try to look into it in the coming days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by the fact that `gstat` cannot generate an experimental variogram given this number of observations:

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)

data <- matrix(c(11.07,42.75,5,62.5,
                 8.73,45.62,234,75,
                 12.62,44.03,12,75,
                 10.87,45.38,67,75,
                 8.79,42.53,64,75),
               nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
names(data) <- c('Lon', 'Lat', 'Elevation', 'Value')
coordinates(data) = ~Lon+Lat
variogram(Value ~ Elevation, data)
## NULL
```

When given insufficient observations, `gstat::variogram` returns `NULL`. This in turn causes autofitVariogram to fail.

The solution is to simply have more data if you want to use kriging. A rule of thumb is that you need about 30 observations to generate a meaningful variogram to fit a variogram model to.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I also come across this problem. I find out the reason is that there are some `Inf` values in my data, and if I delete them, the package works well. Hope this could help you.